# binary composition of structural patterns

Tags: design-patterns

How can I make binary compositions of the next structural design patterns?

- Adapter
- Bridge
- Composite
- Decorator
- Facade
- Flyweight
- Proxy

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for here. Perhaps make an attempt at what you think you need, and we can evaluate that. Also, it wouldn't hurt to explain why you're trying to do this.

Comment: In other words - "how to combine this patterns? Is it possible?"

Comment: Every chapter in the GoF book ends with a _Related Patterns_ section that describes how patterns are combined.